# Nullability analysis fails to warn on null coming from NameValueCollection. Why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Consider a `.net core` project with nullability analysis enabled in `.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>(...)</RootNamespace>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>
(...)
```

Now consider this code:

```cs
public class NullabilityTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        string nullValue = nameValueCollection["I do not exist"];
        Foo(nullValue);
    }

    private void Foo(string shouldBeNotNull) => Assert.NotNull(shouldBeNotNull);
}
```

This code compiles and runs with no warnings, but the test fails on the `Assert.NotNull`. Thus the nullability analysis failed at detecting the null, or even warning about **possible** null. Why? If such situations happen, how can I know when to trust C# 8 nullability analysis?

Comment: Are you sure, that `NameValueCollection` is nullable annotated?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I am not familiar enough with the nullability annotations to know how to check this or how this applies. I guess some of the .NET types  were annotated by the platform authors, but some weren't. Can I somehow tell C# to always treat types and members as possibly nullable, if no annotations are present? Can I add these annotations myself?

Comment: You should be using more modern collections anyway.  Use a dictionary for a collection of keyed pairs, rather than the non-generic version from C# 1.0.  Obsolete types don't get updated.

Comment: Current [sources](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Specialized/System/Collections/Specialized/NameValueCollection.cs,338) tell that indexer returns `string?`, but in .net core 3.1 I see just `string`. I don't know how to annotate the 3rd party libs. You may use different collection, like dictionary, which is annotated already

Comment: The collection comes from [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=netcore-3.1). I am not sure if there exists an alternative with more modern return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NameValueCollection` type simply has not been updated yet. From [Introducing Nullable Reference Types in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/):

> If they add anotations after you, however, then the situation is more annoying. Before they do, you will “wrongly” interpret some of their inputs and outputs as non-null. You’ll get warnings you didn’t “deserve”, *and miss warnings you should have had*. You may have to use ! in a few places, because you really do know better.

(emphasis mine)

In particular, the type is declared as returning the type `string`, which when nullable reference types are enabled, means that the reference cannot be null. The compiler has no reason to think otherwise, so no warning can be emitted.

Since you know that `null` is a possible return value, it's up to you to enforce that. Which you can do by simply declaring the receiving variable with the correct type:

```cs
string? nullValue = (string?)nameValueCollection["I do not exist"];
```

(You need to explicitly cast, because otherwise the compiler's static analysis will still treat the now-nullable `string?` variable as non-null anyway.)

Normally, the ideal way around this would be to use a more modern type. For example, you could use `Dictionary<string, string?>` as an equivalent nullable-aware collection. However, you note that in this case you're getting the collection back from another .NET method ([HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring)).

If you want more robust protection, you can immediately copy the collection to `Dictionary<string, string?>`, or you could implement a wrapper for the `NameValueCollection` type that declares the indexer with the more-correct `string?` return type.

A possible example of the former would be something like this:

```cs
var nameValueDictionary = nameValueCollection
    .Cast<string>()
    .ToDictionary(k => k, k => (string?)nameValueCollection[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a collection of strings - string is naturally a nullable type

You look for an item that doesn't exist and that type will return a null when you request a type that doesn't exist

```
Caution

The Get method does not distinguish between null which is returned because the specified key is not found and null which is returned because the value associated with the key is null.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: _"string is naturally a nullable type"_ -- **false**. When nullable reference types are enabled, `string` is **not nullable**. Only `string?` is nullable. This answer does not answer the question. It fails to explain why the value returned by the `NameValueCollection` indexer, which clearly can return a null value, is permitted to be assigned to a **non-nullable**-typed variable, i.e. `string`.

Comment: Fair enough, had failed to absorb the "with nullability analysis enabled in .csproj:" properly